# Trying to grasp Javascript, but can not get my head around this

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to make this work for days but just can't seem to find any solution to it! I have completed the entire JS tutorial on codecademy and it is still baffling me!

Complete the program below such that the output is the same as that shown 
below. 
Taxi objects should inherit `color`, `numWheels`, and `blowHorn` from Vehicle.

The code I am given is as follows

```
for(var i=0; i<5;   i++) {  
   fleet[i] = new Taxi(i);  
}   

for (var i=0;i<fleet.length;i++) {  
   print("Taxi with badge number " + fleet[i].badgeNumber + " is " + fleet[i].color);   
}   

??????????????? = "White";  

for ( var i=0; i<fleet.length; i++) {   
    print("Taxi with badge number " + fleet[i].badgeNumber + " is " + fleet[i].color);  
    fleet[i].blowHorn();
}
```

And it should print out this when completed:

> Taxi  with    badge   number  0   is  yellow
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  1   is  yellow
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  2   is  yellow
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  3   is  yellow
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  4   is  yellow
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  0   is  White    Beep!
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  1   is  White    Beep!
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  2   is  White    Beep!
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  3   is  White    Beep!
>   Taxi  with    badge   number  4   is  White    Beep!

Comment: In what way does your code not work as expected?  Are you getting an error?  Unexpected output?  When you step through in a debugger, where does it go wrong?  You need to provide at least *some* information about the problem.

Comment: I just don't understand the context of what I have been given. All the things I have looked up online are all browser based. Where as this has to be run in terminal. If anyone could link me to a good site that could help me understand this I would be forever grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't know how to implement that part:

> ??????????????? =   "White";

The most efficient way to do this is to update/change the color value inside the loop. Because you already iterate over each element in the array. So doing this again makes no sense. Just add

> fleet[i].color = "White";

After the print in the first for loop.